# DropboxUnlinkedException - if you have not set an access token pair on the session, or if the user has revoked access

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to dropbox. I have configured manifest file, and written the below code. Please help me understand what I am missing here.
Activity onClick

```
Intent uploadToDropbox = new Intent(this, SUploadDB2Dropbox.class); 
            startService(uploadToDropbox) ;
```

Service SUploadDB2Dropbox

```
private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(God.DROPBOX_APP_KEY,
                God.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(this);
        UploadDB2DropBox upload2DropBox = new UploadDB2DropBox(this, mDBApi);
        upload2DropBox.execute();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

UploadDB2DropBox AsyncTask

```
@Override
    public String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        File file = new File(context.getDatabasePath(God.TABLE_ACTIVATIONS)
                + ".db");
        Log.d(God.TAG,
                "Database path "
                        + context.getDatabasePath(God.TABLE_ACTIVATIONS));

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            String newFileName;
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            newFileName = "/" + God.TABLE_ACTIVATIONS
                    + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".db";
            Log.d(God.TAG, "File path " + file.getName() + " len "
                    + inputStream.available());
            Log.d(God.TAG, " New Filename " + newFileName);
            Entry response = mDBApi.putFile(newFileName, inputStream,
                    file.length(), null, null);
            Log.d(God.TAG, "Uploaded file is " + response.rev);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(God.TAG, "FileNotFoundException");
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();n
            Log.e(God.TAG, "DropboxException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(God.TAG, "IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(God.TAG, "IOException");
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am getting a dropbox exception. The screen does navigate to the dropbox `Allow user` screen (everytime though).

Logcat

```
02-23 11:44:19.435: D/AutoActivate(27289): Database path /data/data/com.swipex.autoactivate/databases/activations
02-23 11:44:19.436: D/AutoActivate(27289): File path activations.db len 8372224
02-23 11:44:19.546: D/AutoActivate(27289):  New Filename /activations1424672059436.db
02-23 11:44:19.702: E/AutoActivate(27289): DropboxException
```

Manifest File

```
<activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="db-KEY_VALUE_HERE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I am getting a UnlinkException

> DropboxUnlinkedException - if you have not set an access token pair on the session, or if the user has revoked access.

What am I missing ?

Comment: To clarify, your **>>EXCEPTION_HERE** marker is on a Log.e line. Is it actually occurring on that line, or on one of the lines above it?

Comment: Sorry, I'll make the correction, I see what you are saying.

Comment: You're pointing out the `putFile` line, but the stack trace doesn't seem to mention this, or even the `UploadDB2DropBox` class you posted. Are you sure this exception is coming from this code? It looks like there's another question about this error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308260/chooseractivity-has-leaked-intentreceiver

Comment: Yes, there are other questions on the unregister exception. I know how to fix them for send sms and send email's, but for dropbox there is a internal registration that happens for a intentservice. Ideally dropbox api should have unregistered. This question is unique for dropbox api's. The regular unregister fixes wont work for this issue.

Comment: Ok, can you clarify why the stack doesn't reference any of your posted code though? And in any case, if you've found a bug in the Dropbox Android Core SDK, please report it along with steps to reproduce it, or ideally a small sample project showing it, here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: Only after I added this code this exception started showing up.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201866499-Dropbox-com-android-packageinstaller-InstallAppProgress-has-leaked-IntentReceiver ]

Comment: As of now, I have given up on dropbox api's. Considering that its badly documented, implemented and supported worse.

Comment: I have added the sample project, here now. I hope this is enough information. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You downvoted the question because I corrected it ? Strange behavior dude. Read the FAQ please. If this is the kind of support you get from dropbox developers, I am not surprised how easily a badly documented (and implemented) can you end up with.. Children..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible dropbox documentation I must say

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(God.TAG, "Initializing Dropbox");
        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(God.DROPBOX_APP_KEY,
                God.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(this);
        if (mDBApi != null && mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
                mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();
                UploadDB2DropBox upload2DropBox = new UploadDB2DropBox(this,
                        mDBApi);
                upload2DropBox.execute();

                //String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.i(God.TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

This helped. I wonder why dropbox keeps asking for permission from the UI. Its stupid to use this api if I have to keep asking for permission.

Comment: Yes, can you suggest the correct answer, I am happy to delete this answer.

Comment: @smarx, you are a dropbox developer, can you answer the question instead of being a downvoter and a critic ?

Comment: I totally agree with you.